# Metro App XAML grid view selected item on initial bind

Tags: c#, xaml, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I am using a GridView in my metro app and have its source set to a CollectionViewSource. Its Selection Mode is set to Single.

The problem I was initially having was preventing the initial item from being selected when the grid loaded. After some research I solved this by setting the IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem property of ListViewBase to false.

However I am also using the ItemListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) to handle selection changed and in here I use itemsviewsource.View.CurrentItem != null to test whether I have an item selected and process some stuff. Unfortuantely on the initial load the CurrentItem is NOT NULL.

My question is, is there anything obvious I am missing in the ItemListView_SelectionChanged event (or anywhere else!) that I can use to check that I have nothing selected on the grids initial load, and bring it into line with what is shows on the UI!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add `this.itemGridView.SelectedIndex=-1;` in the constructor of your page after Initialise. It generally solve the problem of item selected by default (no need to set IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem to false)

Comment: I did try without any joy. The selectedchange event still fires initially with a zero index causing a selection, before then firing with the -1.
I think it must have something to do with setting the source of the Grid to a CollectionViewSource? This appears to, for some reason, fire a selection.

Comment: Yes the problem of default selection is related to CollectionViewSource and when you initialize the ItemsSource

Comment: If you have a Snap view, when you added IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem  did you make sure that you added it also on the ListView of the snapview?

Comment: Otherwise another way is to just set a flag to ignore the first selection changed

Comment: No, don't have a snap view. My 2 grids are inside a semantic zoom control incase that makes a difference. But I set on both.

So, Yep, I've ended up setting a flag for the first load (fired from collection source I think) and then checking for -1 on the next. And setting the IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem to false.